# PostgreSQL-13: Partitioning with overlapping ranges

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-13

I have a blacklist with certain strings beginning with the character '0','1','2',...,'9','a','b','c','d','e','f','?'.

Then I create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE blacklist (concat TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL) PARTITION BY RANGE (concat);
```

Now I do RANGE partitioning:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_0 PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('0') TO ('0ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_0 ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_0 CHECK (concat >= '0' AND concat <= '0ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_1 PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('1') TO ('1ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_1 ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_1 CHECK (concat >= '1' AND concat <= '1ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_2 PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('2') TO ('2ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_2 ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_2 CHECK (concat >= '2' AND concat <= '2ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_3 PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('3') TO ('3ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_3 ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_3 CHECK (concat >= '3' AND concat <= '3ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_4 PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('4') TO ('4ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_4 ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_4 CHECK (concat >= '4' AND concat <= '4ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_5 PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('5') TO ('5ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_5 ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_5 CHECK (concat >= '5' AND concat <= '5ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_6 PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('6') TO ('6ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_6 ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_6 CHECK (concat >= '6' AND concat <= '6ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_7 PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('7') TO ('7ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_7 ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_7 CHECK (concat >= '7' AND concat <= '7ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_8 PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('8') TO ('8ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_8 ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_8 CHECK (concat >= '8' AND concat <= '8ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_9 PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('9') TO ('9ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_9 ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_9 CHECK (concat >= '9' AND concat <= '9ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_a PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('a') TO ('affffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_a ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_a CHECK (concat >= 'a' AND concat <= 'affffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_b PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('b') TO ('bffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_b ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_b CHECK (concat >= 'b' AND concat <= 'bffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_c PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('c') TO ('cffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_c ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_c CHECK (concat >= 'c' AND concat <= 'cffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_d PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('d') TO ('dffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_d ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_d CHECK (concat >= 'd' AND concat <= 'dffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_e PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('e') TO ('effffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_e ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_e CHECK (concat >= 'e' AND concat <= 'effffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_f PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('f') TO ('fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_f ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_f CHECK (concat >= 'f' AND concat <= 'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_rest PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('?') TO ('?ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff');
ALTER TABLE blacklist_list_rest ADD CONSTRAINT blacklist_list_rest CHECK (concat >= '?' AND concat <= '?ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' );
```

I get on Ubuntu 20.04 with postgres 13.1 the following error message:

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist_list_rest PARTITION OF blacklist FOR VALUES FROM ('?') TO ('?ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff');
ERROR:  partition "blacklist_list_rest" would overlap partition "blacklist_list_0"
```

But I have no problem when I run this on my developer station (gentoo linux, postgres 13.1).

Has someone an idea how to fix this? I don't think these characters overlap and I don't think I missed something like regular expressions ('?' should be detected as a character in this scenario).

Comment: Probably collations. Try `concat TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL collate "C"`. Btw: the check constraints are not needed with declarative partitioning (that was needed with old, deprecated inheritance based partitioning)

Comment: Great, thank you! Although I changed the rest table to DEFAULT, I just tested it and I have a "C" COLLATE as default in gentoo but the Ubuntu testbox has "en_US.UTF-8". After adding COLLATE "C" to the blacklist table everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres uses the collations from the operating system, so comparing and sorting strings might differ on different operating systems (or even on the same system when [updates are applied](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2018/08/27/glibc-upgrade.html)). You can force a comparison with "pure" ASCII without using collations using the `"C"` collation:

```
CREATE TABLE blacklist 
(
  concat TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL collate "C"
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (concat);
```